# Select-object -property parameter not displaying multiple column

Tags: powershell

Currently when I try

```
get-process | Select-Object -property NAME,Id,CPU,PM
```

Only the Name column is displayed in vscode in ubuntu

```
Name
----                                                                                      
(sd-pam)                                                                                  
accounts-daemon
```

However if i switch the position of the value 'name' it would work but it seems to only display till where the 'name property is?

```
PS /home/limyk14> get-process | Select-Object -property Id,CPU,name,PM

   Id        CPU Name
   --        --- ----                                                                     
 1506          0 (sd-pam)
```

```
PS /home/limyk14> get-process | Select-Object -property Id,CPU,PM,name

   Id         CPU       PM Name
   --         ---       -- ----
 1506           0   880640 (sd-pam)
  797        2.77    49152 accounts-daemon
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Using PowerShell 5.1 `get-process | Select-Object -property NAME,Id,CPU,PM` shows all properties without problems..

Comment: @iRon the one for vs code was pretty long but -autosize did not seem to help neither does -wrap but when i shift name to the end it works with or without -autosize, maybe just a weird bug on linux??

Comment: What happens if you list just 1 process: `get-process | Select-Object -First 1 -property Id,CPU,PM,name`?

Comment: @iRon

seems ok

`get-process | select-object -first 1 id,name,cpu,pm

  Id Name     CPU     PM
  -- ----     ---     --
1506 (sd-pam)   0 897024 `

i try it with the longest object name i know of - seems fine

`get-process | Where-Object -property id -eq 29747

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName`
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------

but the below fails
`get-process | select-object id,name,cpu,pm  `

   Id Name
   -- ----                                                                                
 1506 (sd-pam)`

Comment: Please, add that to the question. Sorry, I meant: try: [`... |Format-Table -AutoSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) in my earlier comment.

Comment: Following @iRon's line of investigation, can you try this ```get-process | % { $_.Name.Length } | sort-object -desc | select-object -first 1``` - it'll tell you the length of the longest process name. If it's huge you can define some custom formatting for ```Format-Table``` that would restrict the width of the ```Name``` column...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @iRon and @mclayton

It is actually due to the length of a few processes that had really long names
vs code itself was one of them,

Format-table var1,2,3,4 -autosize didn't help neither did wrapping.

However the suggestion of using a hash table and declaring the width works.

```
format-table @{name = 'name';expression = 'name'; width = 7}, cpu, id, pm
```